# Plot numpy matrix as violinplot in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn, violin-plot

I have a problem with a violin plot. I'm trying to create 11 violin plots corresponding to 11 numpy matrices.
I used this code and the result is shown in the figure:

```py
for i in range(0,len(diff)):
    sns.violinplot(y=diff[i],orient='v')
```

[image]

I want to split all the violin plots and put a label below them.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use matplotlib directly, instead of seaborn:

```
diff = np.array([np.random.normal(loc=i, size=(100,)) for i in range(10)])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(0,len(diff)):
    ax.violinplot(dataset=diff[i],positions=[i])
```

[image]

Or, more compact:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.violinplot(dataset=diff.T,positions=range(10))
```

If your numpy arrays are separate:

```
array1 = np.random.normal(loc=0, size=(100,))
array2 = np.random.normal(loc=1, size=(100,))
array3 = np.random.normal(loc=2, size=(100,))
array4 = np.random.normal(loc=3, size=(100,))
array5 = np.random.normal(loc=4, size=(100,))


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i,arr in enumerate([array1, array2, array3, array4, array5]):
    ax.violinplot(dataset=arr,positions=[i])
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i have a different problem, I want to create 11 a violin plot, this 11 violin plot come from 11 different numpy matrix, not one with 11 rows

Comment: is `diff` a list of vectors? Your notation `diff[i]` in your code seem to imply that

Comment: I've added another snippet for how to deal with several separate arrays

Comment: ```diff[i]``` is a list of numpy matrix

Comment: Then the first or last solutions that I propose should get you where you want, don't they?

Comment: with matrix doesn't work, but I solve change matrix to vector with this code
```b=pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(0,len(diff)):
    c=diff[i].ravel()
    c=pd.DataFrame(c)
    c.columns=[lista_date[i]]
    b=pd.concat((b,c),axis=1)
    b=b.dropna()

[row,col]=b.shape

for i in range(0,col):
    plt.violinplot(dataset=b[lista_date[i]],positions=[i])```

Answer (score 1):

Or if you want to use `seaborn`:

```py
diff = np.array([np.random.normal(loc=i, size=(100,)) for i in range(10)])
sns.violinplot(data=diff.T)
```

[image]